# Is there any specific meaning or history behind flowers on the front luggage rack?

Tags: bike-culture

I have seen this multiple times in Belgium,  and also recently even here in Switzerland my co-worker bought a bicycle with (in her case artificial) flowers permanently fixed on a front luggage rack. Looks as if the bicycle is used to transport the flowers ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bike_and_flowers_2.jpg)):

[image]

I have also seen a sculpture of the bicycle with flowers in Amsterdam, attached to the wall.

Due observing this motive repeatedly, I would like to ask if is it some known origin,  motive, history, symbolism or bicycle culture thing behind this decoration. I mean, it is not very usual to decorate vehicles with flowers, and they have always been specifically on the front luggage rack.

Comment: I've seen cars with fake eyelashes, eyelids, noses, propellors, flags, and any number of stickers.  Making one's ride pretty has been a thing since someone put ribbons and flowers in the mane of their horse.

Comment: I've seen it in France too, and in my garage here in the UK I have a wicker front basket with artificial flowers on (not mine!)

Answer (score 3):

The flowers are there for the owner to find his or her bicycle. If your bicycle looks too much like a thousand others, it is hard to locate large parking rack or if you forget where you have parked it. Also when and if stolen it may be almost impossible to recover your bike if it has no personalization. People who have custom built bicycles are less likely to decorate them, whereas those who have a "bone stock" bicycle directly from the manufacturer are more likely to add decorations.

Comment: Not very serious but at least fun

Comment: It is also a kind of fashion thing, at least in the Netherlands, it comes and goes in waves.